# Draw squares in random colors using Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need a new random color for every new smaller square. Now it changes color only after while loop. Could you help  me fix it?

```
def random_color():
    colvar=random.randint(0,10)
    L=['red','blue','green','yellow','black','pink','gold','violet','coral','lemon chiffon','sea green'] #wiki.tcl.tk/16166  website which I used to find names for colors
    result=L[colvar]
    return result

def square(color,x,y):     
     turtle.color(color)
     turtle.begin_fill()
     turtle.penup()
     turtle.goto(x,y)
     turtle.pendown()
     line1=200           #creates a new smaller square
     while line1>=10:   
      line1=line1-10
      for i in range(2):
          turtle.forward(line1)
          turtle.right(90)
          turtle.forward(line1)
          turtle.right(90)

def drawsqr():
    num=5               
    for i in range(num):  
              color=random_color()  #change color after each complete cycle
              x=250
              y=250
              square(color,x,y)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand you solved your issue, but **random.choice()** is better suited in your function:

```
def random_color():
    L=['red','blue','green','yellow','black','pink','gold','violet','coral','lemon', 'chiffon','seagreen'] 
    return random.choice(L)
```

Comment: Thanks I  didn't know about random.choice()

Answer (score 1):

> I understand you solved your issue, but random.choice() is better
>   suited in your function:

I disagree.  The problem with `random.choice()` is you can get the same color on successive calls which is what you don't want:

```
>>> import random
>>> COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'gold', 'violet', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan']
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print(random.choice(COLORS))
... 
green
pink
red
black
violet
orange
orange
violet
yellow
yellow
>>>
```

Using `random.shuffle()` in combination with `itertools.cycle()` gives you a randomized sequence of colors that repeats from which you can pluck unlike colors one after another:

```
import turtle
import random
import itertools

COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'gold', 'violet', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan']

def random_color(iterator=[]):  # intentional dangerous default value
    if not iterator:  # empty container
        colors = COLORS
        random.shuffle(colors)
        iterator.append(itertools.cycle(colors))

    return next(iterator[0])

def square(length, x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    while length >= 10:
        color = random_color()  # change color after each square
        turtle.color(color)

        turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.right(90)

        turtle.end_fill()

        length -= 10

square(200, -100, 100)

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
imputturtlegraphics,
setpcolor:("red,green,blue,gold,puple,maroon,claret,tuquoise etc")
,pendown
,goto("x$y$")
,movehundredstepsforward
,turnleft90
repeatprev2sX4
```